# Set UIColor in storyboard from variable/constant

Tags: swift, storyboard, ios9, uicolor

How do I set, let's say a text color on a UILabel, to a color defined in one of my classes like:

```
func mainAppColor() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.3, blue: 0.4, alpha: 1)
}
```

or

```
let mainAppColor = UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.3, blue: 0.4, alpha: 1)
```

in storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

If your method is declared in some other class like:

```
class TextColorClass {

    func mainAppColor() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.3, blue: 0.4, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

Then you can use it by make instance of that class this way:

```
let classInstance = TextColorClass()
yourLBL.textColor = classInstance.mainAppColor()
```

If it is declared like:

```
class TextColorClass {

    let mainAppColor = UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.3, blue: 0.4, alpha: 1)
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
let classInstance = TextColorClass()
yourLBL.textColor = classInstance.mainAppColor
```

If that method is declare in same class suppose in `ViewController` class then you can use it this way:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    yourLBL.textColor = mainAppColor()
}

func mainAppColor() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.3, blue: 0.4, alpha: 1)
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to set any property from storyboard you can use `@IBInspectable` as shown in below example code:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class PushButtonView: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var fillColor: UIColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    @IBInspectable var isAddButton: Bool = true

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {


    }

}
```

And assign this class to your button.like shown into below Image:

[image]

And if you go to the Attribute Inspector you can see custom property for that button.

[image]

Now you can set it as per your need.

For more Info refer this tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/90690/modern-core-graphics-with-swift-part-1

Comment: And the most obvious way to do something like this would be to declare it as a static, which makes it a class value, so you don't need to create an instance to use it.  `static let mainColor =...` and then just TextColorClass.mainColor..

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion..:) @DavidBerry

Comment: But that is not using storyboard... I know how to set a property in code, just not in storyboard using constants.